# import csv file to sql database in c# window application without header row

Tags: c#, database, winforms, csv, import

I am trying to import a `.csv` file into database in C# windows application without header row.

Thank you to all.

My .csv file format is

```
001,0000002226,01,2011/03/27,07:07,        
001,0000009392,01,2011/03/27,07:12,        
001,0000002220,01,2011/03/27,07:17,        
001,0000002121,01,2011/03/27,07:19,        
001,0000002205,01,2011/03/27,07:20,        
001,0000002125,01,2011/03/27,07:25,        
001,0000002270,01,2011/03/27,07:30,        
001,0000009050,03,2011/03/27,07:34,        
001,0000002251,03,2011/03/27,07:34,        
001,0000002141,01,2011/03/27,07:36,        
001,0000002236,01,2011/03/27,07:42,        
001,0000002169,01,2011/03/27,07:43,
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] that outlines what you've tried please?

Comment: First approach (completely handwritten): Open file, read line by line, on every line: split into your values, use SqlCommand to execute an insert (and PLEASE use the parametrized Version). Quit simple tasks. If you stuck with one part, ask that part again. And if you stuck on another part, ask again.

Comment: Second method: Use the "Build In" TextFieldParser (although in Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO Namespace, you CAN use it from C#).

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use a 3rd party like [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/); then you can use attributes to ignore the first row, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11004284/1791065).

Comment: Using 3rd party libs for such a simple task is llike growing a cow to drink a glass of milk once in a quarter.